# Difference Between Appmodule vs Pages module in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngx-bootstrap

I have just cloned [this](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin) project , Now this has two kinds of modules one that is inside page and other on root directory.

**Directory Tree:**
[image]

**App.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform- 
browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CoreModule } from './@core/core.module';
import { ThemeModule } from './@theme/theme.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';  

import {
 NbChatModule,
 NbDatepickerModule,
 NbDialogModule,
 NbMenuModule,
 NbSidebarModule,
 NbToastrModule,
 NbWindowModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
@NgModule({
declarations: [AppComponent],
 imports: [

BrowserModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
HttpClientModule,
AppRoutingModule,

ThemeModule.forRoot(),

NbSidebarModule.forRoot(),
NbMenuModule.forRoot(),
NbDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
NbDialogModule.forRoot(),
NbWindowModule.forRoot(),
NbToastrModule.forRoot(),
NbChatModule.forRoot({
  messageGoogleMapKey: 'AIzaSyA_wNuCzia92MAmdLRzmqitRGvCF7wCZPY',
}),
CoreModule.forRoot(),
FormsModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,


],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**Pages.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NbMenuModule } from '@nebular/theme';

import { ThemeModule } from '../@theme/theme.module';
import { PagesComponent } from './pages.component';
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module';
import { ECommerceModule } from './e-commerce/e-commerce.module';
import { PagesRoutingModule } from './pages-routing.module';
import { MiscellaneousModule } from './miscellaneous/miscellaneous.module';
import { AlertService, AuthenticationService, UserService, 
   SiteSearchService, LayoutService } from '../pages/services/index';
  import { AuthGuard } from '../pages/guards';
  import { AppConfig } from '../app.config';
  import { JwtInterceptor } from '../pages/helpers/jwt.interceptor';
  import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';  
  import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
  import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

  import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';  
  @NgModule({
  imports: [
   PagesRoutingModule,
  ThemeModule,
   NbMenuModule,
   DashboardModule,
   ECommerceModule,
  MiscellaneousModule,
   FormsModule,
   ReactiveFormsModule,
],
 declarations: [
 PagesComponent, 
 LoginComponent
  ],
 providers: [
 AuthGuard,
 AlertService,
 AuthenticationService,
 UserService, AppConfig,
 SiteSearchService,
  LayoutService,

   { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },


] 
})
   export class PagesModule {
}
```

**Issue:**

Issue is this despite of declaring  LoginComponent inside pages module I see this

> Component LoginComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

Also I have tried to import this inside app.module but no luck.
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct structure would be `LoginComponent` inside the `declarations` array of the `PagesModule`, and the `PagesModule` inside the `imports` array of the `AppModule`.

It completely depends on the architecture of your application though. You might be lazy loading the `PagesModule`, for example, which would mean it should not be imported, or you might be using the `LoginComponent` outside of the `PagesModule`, which would mean it should be exported out of it.

In Angular, every component must be declared inside a module, and only one module. Modules can be imported as many times as you want in different modules though, and because modules can also export components, you can use those components throughout the application. `AppModule` is by default the root module of an Angular application. Any other module is what is commonly referred to as a "feature module". I'd read carefully the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules)